# In Angular, how can I provide an argument to a class' constructor which itself is provided in a component?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a class similar to this:

```js
export class SomeClass {
  constructor(someService: SomeService, someString: string)​ { ​... }
  ...
}
```

I am trying to use this class inside a component like so:

```js
@Component(
  selector: ..., ...,
  providers: [{ provide: SomeClass, useClass: SomeClass, deps: [SomeService] }]
)
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private someClass: SomeClass) { ... }
  ...
}
```

How can I tell Angular what value to give to `someString`?

I tried specifying the value inside `deps`, I tried providing it separately like so:

```js
  providers: [
    { provide: "someString", useValue: "someValue" },
    { provide: SomeClass, useClass: SomeClass, deps: [SomeService] }
  ]
```

As well as other things which I can't really remember.

`someService` is always set correctly, but `someValue` is always undefined.

I don't know if this has been asked before. If it has, I wasn't able to find the question.

At Octavian Mărculescu's suggestion, I tried setting up an injection token

```js
export const TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('TokenDesc');
export class SomeClass {
  constructor(someService: SomeService, @Inject(TOKEN) someValue: string)​ { ​... }
  ...
}
```

as well as provide a value for it:

```js
  providers: [
    { provide: TOKEN, useValue: "someValue" },
    { provide: SomeClass, useClass: SomeClass, deps: [SomeService] }
  ]
```

Still, I only get back undefined. I also tried

```js
useValue: { key: "someValue" }
```

with the same result. Maybe I am misusing the injection token method?

Comment: You should have a look at the [`InjectionToken` concept](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken). This should help you inject whatever you need. You also have usage notes down below to help you understand how to use it properly.

Comment: What kind of data are you holding in SomeClass ? What is the purpose of SomeClass ? Is it a service, is it a data model, a component maybe ?

Comment: @StefanP It just contains a couple of methods I keep using in a few separate components. It's not 
something I want to inject into the entire module or root.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I added my attempt to use injection tokens but I am still unable to get a value in my class.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I also need to add the token to `deps`.
Below is the complete code.

```js
// some-class.ts
export const TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>('TokenDesc');
export class SomeClass {
  constructor(someService: SomeService, @Inject(TOKEN) someValue: string)​ { ​... 
}
  ...
}

// some-component.ts
@Component(
  selector: ..., ...,
  providers: [
    { provide: TOKEN, useValue: "someValue" },
    { provide: SomeClass, useClass: SomeClass, deps: [SomeService, TOKEN] }
                                       // This is what was missing ^^^^^
  ]
)
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private someClass: SomeClass) { ... }
  ...
}
```